# Selenium не видит драйвер из Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Поставил себе в проект:

Selenium.WebDrive

Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

при запуске выдает в строке

```
var driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

*OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary'*

даже с репозитория самого WebDriver.ChromeDriver по ссылке ниже выдает такая же ошибка. Почему-то Selenium не видит или не принимает исполняемый файл chrome хотя при запуске он успешно создает файл chromedriver.exe. Пытался передавать путь ошибка так же выходит.

https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/tree/master/TestDrives

Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Твой хром видимо установлен по нестандартному пути. Или не установлен вообще.

Или поставь хром по стандартному пути или же задавай адрес вручную в настройках драйвера.

Comment: а при чем тут хром? я думал этот хром драйвер это и есть хром только урезанный

Comment: ХромДрайвер фактически это связующее звено между твоей программой и хромом. Нету хрома - нету с чем "связывать".

Comment: теперь понял, спасибо